# Using memcached failover servers in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, memcached

I'm trying to set up a robust *memcached* configuration for a nodejs app with the [node-memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached) driver, but it does not seem to use the specified failover servers when one server dies.

My local experiment goes as follows:

**shell**

```
memcached -p 11212
```

**node**

```
MC = require('memcached')
c = new MC('localhost:11211', //this process does not exist
            {failOverServers: ['localhost:11212']})
c.get('foo', console.log) //this will eventually time out
c.get('foo', console.log) //repeat 5 or 6 times to exceed the retries number
//wait until all the connection errors appear in the console
//at this point, the failover server should be in use
c.get('foo', console.log) //this still times out :(
```

Any ideas of what might we be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the failover feature is somewhat buggy in [node-memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached).

To enable failover you must set the `remove` options:

```
c = new MC('localhost:11211', //this process does not exist
            {failOverServers: ['localhost:11212'],
             remove : true})
```

Unfortunately, this is not going to work because of the following error:

```
[depricated] HashRing#replaceServer is removed.
[depricated] the API has no replacement
```

That is, when trying to replace a dead server with a replacement from the failover list, node-memcached outputs a deprecation error from the [HashRing](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-hashring) library (which, in turn, is maintained by the same author of node-memcached). IMHO, feel free to open a bug :-)

Comment: yeah, we tried with that option too but didn't work either :(

Answer (score -1):

This is come when your nodejs server not getting any session id from memcached
Please check properly in php.ini file you are setting properly or not for memcached

session.save = 'memcache'
session.path = 'tcp://localhost:11212'

Comment: php.ini? what are you talking about? :-|